# code error postback

Tags: php

Could someone help me to check my code, no matter what value i clicked,the radio always checked on the last one. it doesn't postback correctly, however the return "echo" value is right.

Thanks a lot

here is my code

```
<html>
  <form id="form" name="form"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Apple" checked="checked" <?php if(isset($_POST['foo']) == 'Apple'): echo "checked='checked'"; endif; ?>/>Apple
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Banana"  <?php if(isset($_POST['foo']) == 'Banana'): echo "checked='checked'"; endif; ?>/>Banana
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Orange" <?php if(isset($_POST['foo']) == 'Orange'): echo "checked='checked'"; endif; ?>/>Orange

<input type="submit" value="Confirm" /> </form>

<? if(isset($_POST['foo']))
{echo $_POST['foo'];
}
?>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparisons are based on the return value of [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset), when they should be testing the value of `$_POST['foo']`, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'Orange'):
```

Otherwise, `true == 'Orange'` actually [comes out true](http://viper-7.com/xo7Bs2) because PHP is loosely typed and doing type coercion behind the scenes, which is why you're getting this strange result.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, I think I did something the same way wrong. Now I understood how to fix it :-) thanks again

Comment: I know this is slightly off-topic @nickb, but could you give a good reason for why people would still use `==` instead of `===` in PHP? I just don't see any point of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) == 'Orange')
```

`isset` returns true or false, and due to PHP's weak comparison, `true == 'Orange'`. You'll want to do this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'Orange')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got it now :-)

Comment: @pst If you don't have isset and PHP tries to reference a non-existent key of an array, it will emit an error... won't it?